# Технология доступа к БД на сервера в Android Studio

Tags: java, база-данных, android-studio, visual-studio

При работе с DOT.NET мы можем использовать встроенные инструменты для работы с бд на сервере. Например Datagridview, в свойствах которой подключаемая к нужному серверу.
Есть ли что-то подобное в Android Studio? Могу ли я использовать базу данных на сервере, подключаясь к ней и работая так же просто, как в Visual Studio, то есть чтобы пользователь без труда редактировал  записи, или там не таких удобных встроенных средств и делать это надо вручную? Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В Android Studio работают многие (а может даже и все) плагины от JetBrains Intellij IDEA
[image: плагины по работе с БД]